# Why would you ever stash changes instead of creating a local commit or a temporary branch?

Tags: git, github, gitlab

I'm having a hard time understanding why anyone would ever use `git stash` when it seems to be an inferior option.

As far as I can tell, `git stash`'s use case is to save work in progress that you have on a branch when you go work on another branch.

Usually, when I am in this situation, I run this instead:

```
$ git add --all
$ git commit -m "WIP: some info about the changes"
```

and go work on the other branch. When I come back to the branch I was working on, I can simply run `git reset HEAD~1` to go back to my previous commit and resume where I was, or stack WIP commits until I'm done and I squash them.

Compared to using `git stash`, this seems to me like the superior option:

- I can always run `git pull --rebase` to update my branch and rebase my WIP on top
- I can cherry-pick my WIP on another branch if necessary

If I want to, I can even run `git checkout -b temporary_branch` before creating my commit so that it is located in a temporary branch instead of the one I was working on:

- this gives me the usual benefits of branches, i.e. I can have several WIP in parallel
- this is also reassuring because it's easier to lose stashed changes than committed changes; if my company's policy allows it (it does), I can even push the temporary branch to ensure I can't lose my changes even if something happens to my computer (while you can't push a stash)

Because of all that, I currently see absolutely no reason to ever use `git stash`.
So... what am I missing? I assume the people making git wouldn't include such a command if you could already do everything rather simply without it

Comment: Why did someone tag this as a duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20537223/what-is-the-intended-use-case-for-git-stash ? I'm not asking what can be done with git stash, I'm asking why you would do it that way when this seems like an inferior option to me

Comment: I have edited my question to make it more clear how it's different from the other one. I'm asking for it to be reopened

Answer (score 2):

The git commit is a part of the project history, which can be obviously reverted by the `git reset` command.

Stashing is a powerfull helper command to "temporarly park" your source code. You can choose to get it back by `git stash pop` or to drop it by `git stash drop`.

A frequent scenario where **stash** is a primary tool is the following:

1. You modified the source code.
2. You discover that you are on a wrong branch, for example on the **master** instead of **feature** branch.
3. Now you stash the changes by `git stash -u` (the untracked ones too).
4. Change branch by `git checkout feature`.
5. Get back stashed changes by `git stash pop`.

Answer (score 0):

for example you're experimenting something new and you broke something,

and you don't understand how that piece of code was working before,

so you stash the changes, have a look at the code that is working,

after you apply the stash back and fix it or undo some of your changes