# What's the difference between "Discard all changes" and "Stash all changes"?

Tags: git, visual-studio-code, command-line-interface

I want to undo the command `npm create vite@latest`. I want to revert my changes without them showing up in git log or them being saved.

In Visual Studio Code's *Source Control* tab there are two buttons on top of unstaged changes, which appear when you hover over them:

[image]

On hover one says:

[image]

And the other reads:

[image]

What is the difference between them?

How can I replicate their behavior with the Git CLI?

Comment: That is criminally bad UI design, given how different these options are.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

- If you choose "Discard", your changes are gone and there will be no simple way of recovering them (see [How do you undo "Discard all changes" in VS Code/Git](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43541167/how-do-you-undo-discard-all-changes-in-vs-code-git)).

  The corresponding Git command is something like

  ```
  git restore <file>
  ```

  or

  ```
  git checkout -- <file>
  ```

  e.g., you can use `git restore .` or `git checkout -- .` to discard everything.

  (There are several possible commands which have similar effects; see [How do I revert all local changes in Git managed project to previous state?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1146973/how-do-i-revert-all-local-changes-in-git-managed-project-to-previous-state))
- If you choose "Stash", your changes will temporarily be removed, but you will be able to recover them later (see e.g. [What is the intended use-case for git stash?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20537223/what-is-the-intended-use-case-for-git-stash) or https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Git-Tools-Stashing-and-Cleaning).

  The corresponding Git command is

  ```
  git stash
  ```